# assignment of undefined variables in Jinja2

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I got this piece of YAML and i want jinja2 to assign and create item.menu, if it is not previously defined.

```
data:
  - name: bar
    menu: blah
  - name: foo
```

This is my code, the error-output ist "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block'"

```
{% for item in data %}
{% if item.menu is not defined %}
{% set item.menu=item.name %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any Help about what I did wrong would be much apretiated :)
Greetings, Hendrik

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You're question is not clear but here is my answer. I'll make everything explicit :

```
{% for item in data %}
{% if item.menu is not defined %}
{{ item.name }}
{% else %}
{{ item.menu }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```